# How can I implement a secure websocket (wss://) implementation in C# vss 2010 or less?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, websocket, .net-4.5

How can I implement a secure websocket (wss://) implementation in C# vss 2010 or less? because in .net 4.5 it has implementation of WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are talking about websockets for .NET 4.0 and C#?
In that case I know of XSockets.NET (http://xsockets.net) or super websocket (on codeplex I think) that support certificates. Might be others as well on .NET 4

Regards
Uffe